# How do you trace posts from inactive members?

Tags: support, search

I read an interesting post by post by user # xyxy. I tried to reach other posts by the same author, searching by *user:xyxy*, but I didn't get any returns, since the account has been deleted. Is it impossible or there is a way?

Comment: What do you mean by *"post by post by user # xyxy"* (seems incomprehensible, unless "by post" is left out)? What was the intent?

Comment: Direct searches using the regular search box, but this post on the main Meta shows how this can be accomplished with a SEDE querry:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280840